# Как убрать повторное появление после выполнения команды onclicl?

Tags: javascript

Есть такая строка:

```
 <span class='ley-toggle' onclick="$('#layered_block_left').toggle(1000);">Показать фильтр</span></div>
```

После вывода фильтра и отработки его появляется повторно данная строка.

Извиняюсь за скудность информации, в javascript не понимаю практически ничего, спрашивайте, готов предоставить любую информацию.

Comment: не делайте onclick в разметке, особенно используя jQuery.

Comment: а что использовать?

Comment: @eicto
человек же написал,что не шарит,какой смысл говорить ему,как делать не надо,не говоря при этом как делать надо?

@intertex
вместо инлайнового onclick используйте такую конструкцию - 
$('.ley-toggle').on('click',function(){
   $('#layered_block_left').toggle(1000);
});

Comment: Сделал так:
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.ley-toggle').on('click',function(){ $('#layered_block_left').toggle(200);}) return false;
</script>
Результат тот же.

Comment: Блин, я минут десять читаю и не могу понять, что же все-таки ты хочешь сделать. Опиши, пожалуйста, более подробно, что должно происходить. И чье это свойство "#layered_block_left"? Предполагаю, что div'a. Тогда, что с этим div'om должно происходить?

И причем здесь событие toggle, почему оно в конце нового объекта?!

Comment: я понял.. у ОП некая форма (обычная, не ajax), в ней фильтр. он хочет чтобы если пользователь нажал "показать", то она всегда стала показаной (после сабмита). 

@intertex напишите в css что-то вроде, `.filter-shown #layered_block_left { display: block; }` а на серверной стороне в коде, добавляйте класс filter-shown к body или html при генерации ответа (можно вообще к любому родительскому блоку для `#layered_block_left`, если надо навсегда, то в сессию запишите. второй вариант localStorage/cookie

Comment: @eicto, @mccrush, @Darth, вот попробуйте сделать фильтр несколько раз: http://demo.sibspace.ru/25-akkumuljatory

Кнопка "Показать фильтр" после каждого раза дублируется, и не всегда успеваешь выбрать параметр, по которому нужно отфильтровать.

Comment: @intertex у вас неправильный результат в ajax возвращается, и в строчке `$('#layered_block_left').replaceWith(utf8_decode(result.filtersBlock));` вы добавляете не только новый `#layered_block_left` а ещё и кнопку с фильтрами.

Comment: @eicto, убрал данное условие, помогло)

Осталось только еще найти строку, которая отвечает отвечает за выпадающий список, а что нет возможности выбрать из него параметр. При нажатии на фильтр сразу обрабатывается запрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@intertex](/users/8975/intertex)](/users/8975/intertex) у вас неправильный результат в ajax возвращается, и в строчке `$('#layered_block_left').replaceWith(utf8_decode(result.filtersBlock));` 
вы добавляете не только новый #layered_block_left а ещё и кнопку с фильтрами.

[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto), убрал данное условие, помогло